# Do I have to use HTML code to make a github.io page?

Tags: github-pages

I've been trying to make a GitHub.io page but the steps say to create an index.html file with code in it. I have no experience with HTML though. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: I guess you could use a WYSIWYG editor or something like that, but ultimately it's still generating HTML code. There's no other way to make a web page.

Answer (score -1):

I found this answer on khan academy so it isn't by me but I hope it helps:

**Github Pages**

Github has a feature called Github Pages, which makes it easy and free for you to create a multi-file website hosted at yourusername.github.io.

**Answer**

Code repositories can contain all sorts of types of code, not just HTML and CSS - whatever code is needed to make the project work.

Comment: Although probably not the right place to ask this question. But you can create a repo with the same user name and host an index.html file and from the setting, you can enable github.io